# Server to multiple client communication

Tags: sockets, networking, client-server, real-time

I'm looking for a way to be able to push data from the server to the client.  For instance I have a two clients and a server.  Client A  does an update which updates the server, now I want the server to push that update down to the other client B.

Here's three options I can come up with.

1) Keep a connection open the whole time from the client to the server.
2) Use UDP packets (nat traversal might be an issue here, maybe?)
3) Have client polling the server at a high frequency to see if there's a change.

I don't really like option 1 because I feel if there are lots and lots of clients then we may run out of tcp ports?    #2 seems like we could have a NAT issue, meaning the client will have to make sure a port is opened,  I guess the client could use UPnP for that but then I would have to write extra code to make sure I got all the packets needed.   #3 just seems like it's not really real time then and opening and closing a connection all the time just seems dirty.

Are there any other recommendations out there?  How does dropbox handle this or Exchange server?

Comment: If you really need 'real-time' why are you comparing it to DropBox and Exchange Server, which are certainly *not* real-time? Or are you just misusing 'real-time'?

Comment: I might be misusing real time.  So with dropbox you add a file on one machine and it seems like instantly it shows up on the other machine.  I'm curious on the client B side how the proper way to do this is.

Comment: 'Real-time' in computing implies specific timing *constraints.*

Comment: You can check for consistent periodically ? won't that help ?

Ex - Run a thread which will try to connect to server periodically and check consistent of your files or whatever.

Comment: Also you can have some feature in your client which check it's own consistency using some kind of HASH. when it see a change it tries to update server. And server if other client is online ill push the updates

Comment: How many clients do you expect your server to need to handle simultaneously?  I'd say if it's less than 1000, option (1) is workable.  If it's more than that, you'll probably want to do something more elaborate (which might just be multiple threads or processes, each one handling up to 1000 connections; See this article for some other possibilities:  http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conceptual answer,

At client side you can run a thread/process checking for your specific data consistency periodically. When a change is noted it will push these changes to server [You can use HASH for check consistency and use separate threads to push data if server has slots for client connections]

Now at server when it get NEW updates it checks for other clients of same user [ like mobile phone or other PC ]. Each client will have a thread for listen to server and when server sees other connections as I mentioned it will try to locate then and push updates to them. Note that you will need ports dedicated for these services to run and I think that's the way services you mentioned work

-Happy Coding-